How to get a sf dataframe object from R into ArcGIS Pro with correct CRS
I have a dataset in CRS EPSG:7842. I fit a KDE (from kde()) to the dataset, and now the dataset (kde_all) has two columns: kde_value and geometry. The geometry column now contains polygons (POLYGON) instead of points (POINT). Each polygon represents an area where the KDE value has been estimated.
Additionally, I have dataset of GPS points from an animal, and ultimately I want to combine the two so that at every GPS point, I also have the human population density estimate - and I wanted to do this part in ArcGIS Pro. The animal GPS points are in Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994, CRS 4283.
I wanted to transform the data to match my GPS data, so I used this code:
kde_all_gda94 <- st_transform(kde_all, crs = 4283)

But it doesn't work - it just produces a single line out in the ocean, and I have no idea why.
This is the code I used to get the KDE:
humanpop <- sf::st_as_sf(humanpop_raw, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = "epsg:7842")
cell_size <- 500
band_width <-5000
kdegrid <- humanpop%>% create_grid_rectangular(cell_size = cell_size, side_offset = (band_width)*3)
kde_all <- humanpop%>%
  kde(band_width = band_width, kernel = "quartic", grid = kdegrid, weights = HPD$Weight, scaled = FALSE)

And if I try to write to a shapefile the KDE data without transforming to a different CRS:
Warning message:
In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
  GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: Geocentric CRS not supported in WKT1_ESRI

I am not sure where the issue is: why I can't just transform the CRS and get the KDE polygons at the right location in ArcGIS Pro?
For reference, here is a the first three rows of my humanpop_raw data:



Habitat
x
y
Weighting




Urban
422916.8
6384610
1441


Urban
453260.1
6417406
869


Urban
456593.7
6421370
762




Cell size of 500 degrees?? EPSG:7842 is GDA2020 geographic. You're going all the way round the world in one cell. You have an ArcGIS Desktop tag but don't mention anything about this in your question, is that correct or did you forget to include a bit?

Apologies, ArcGIS Desktop was a mistaken tag. I did not realise the cell size was in degrees (I thought it would be in meters). Thank you for highlighting that.

In fact, EPSG:7842 has metres as the unit (according to https://epsg.io/7842) - so does 500 not mean the cell size is just 500 meters?

I saw that in the epsg.io entry... I don't see how it could be possible to have units:metres with no projection method defined. The WKT reads GEOCCS["GDA2020"... so it's a geographic coordinate system; It reads like a 3d version of EPSG:7844 but EPSG:7842 is not recognized by ArcGIS. Are you sure your data is in this CRS?

I'm not really sure how to answer that as I'm quite new to all this - I assumed with this humanpop <- sf::st_as_sf(humanpop_raw, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = "epsg:7842")
I was inherently setting the humanpop to be epsg:7842. When I do st_crs(humanpop) it says it is GEOGCRS["GDA2020",
DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 2020", ...

Perhaps use EPSG:7844 if your data is in geographic coordinates, Esri will recognize that one. Then use a cell size in decimal degrees (around 0.005 degrees would be close to 500m). It's true you're asserting a coordinate reference system but if your data is not in geographic coordinates things will go very wrong, can you post a sample of the contents of humanpop_raw.

I've added a data sample. I did try using EPSG:7844 in the initial st_as_sf function and 0.005 degrees, but would get this error when creating the grid:
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : !anyNA(x) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In st_is_longlat(x) :
bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
2: In st_is_longlat(x) :
bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
I know I have no NAs in the data, so not sure what that error is referring to.

It's not geographic data, those coordinates look like MGA coordinates, you must find the correct coordinate system to match your data, it would be best to go back to where you got it from and check the metadata to find out what the correct EPSG is. There's usually only one or two zones for each state, you could try https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/add-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm with each MGA zone to see if this data is in MGA (the most likely), if it's recent it should be MGA2020 with EPSG code 78XX where XX is the zone ID, from 48 to 56.

Yeah so this dataset came from someone else, but as they understand it the data is from MGA2020 EPSG:7842 OR from EPSG:7844 - I have tried with both and neither work; 7844 gives the bounding box error, and using 7842 - well you can see the issue I have there in my original question.

Ah, my apologies - you were right! Looking at a map of the coordinate systems showed that I had the wrong final two numbers (also when you mentioned it should be from 48 to 56. It works once I used EPSG 7856. Thank you!

I see, East coast of Australia, near Newcastle, that makes sense.
